# How to show progress bar on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem Statement:**

> I want a video which will play on hover but when video will play there
>    should show a **progress bar** for that

I got this tutorial which is working but now **I want to add progress bar as well on hover**

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yc4bwyma/)

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $('.video').each(function(i, obj) {
        $(this).on("mouseover", function() { hoverVideo(i); });
        $(this).on("mouseout", function() { hideVideo(i); });
    });
});

function hoverVideo(i) {  
    $('.thevideo')[i].play(); 
}

function hideVideo(i) {
    $('.thevideo')[i].pause(); 
}
```

**EDIT:**

New Problem statement:

---

> On hover progress will show for video this problem is solved  but now
>   **I want the progress bar is working in circle on the video.**

Comment: Here is a link which is working fine but i also need a progress bar on hover http://jsfiddle.net/yc4bwyma/

Answer (score 1):

Use Html5 feature and jQuery.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/qgy57af9/10/

```
<div id="video-holder" style="width:100%;position: absolute;">
    <video id="video" style="width:100%">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">

    </video>    
        <progress id='p' max='100' value='0'><span>0</span>% played</progress>
</div>
```

And now for **Progress bar** use this code:

```
$('#p').css('display','none');
$('video').hover(function(){
   $('#video')[0].play();
    $('#p').css('display','block');

}, function(){
    $('#video')[0].pause();
     $('#p').css('display','none');
});

var video = document.getElementById('video');
var pBar = document.getElementById('p');
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  var percent = Math.floor((100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime);
  pBar.value = percent;
  pBar.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = percent;
}, false);
```

**EDIT :**

For circular progress bar use Progressbar.js

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/grwkhnuq/2/

see this example

```
var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#container', {
    color: '#FCB03C',
     strokeWidth: 2
});


$('video').hover(function(){
   $('#video')[0].play();
   $('#video')[0].play();
   // $('#container').css('display','block');

}, function(){
    $('#video')[0].pause();
    // $('#container').css('display','none');
});

var video = document.getElementById('video');
//var pBar = document.getElementById('p');
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  var percent = Math.floor((100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime);
    console.log(percent);
    circle.animate(percent/100, function() {

    });
}, false);
```

Comment: Rather: http://jsfiddle.net/qgy57af9/11/ (+ using the right classes instead of those IDs)

Comment: You guys have done very well but i also want to make this progress bar in circle like there will be a circle and on hover a border will run around the circle as a progress bar.. Hope you get what i mean!

Comment: @Keval Bhatt  can you help me more to make this video full heigh?

http://client-acumenadagency.com/sed/

Comment: @ HMS see in answer I tried with circular progress bar now apply css and adjust your element maybe it will help to you

Comment: @Keval Bhatt  when i add this new javascript to my html, video doesnot work so should i also include Progressbar.js  ?

Comment: yes you have to include progressbar.js it is  an lib file and your video not working bcz your application doesn't find progressbar.js  so your appliation crashed !

Comment: @Keval Bhatt Sorry no :(