# Animate progress bar on hover and reverse animate on exit?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to do something like https://2016.makemepulse.com (the click and hold bit) where

1. on hover, progress bar animates forward trying to get to 100
2. on exit, bar animates backward trying to get to 0 (if not already at 0)

Theres a lot of on hover animate forward examples and currently trying [How to show progress bar on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424755/how-to-show-progress-bar-on-hover)

But it doesn't go backwards on exit. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run an interval function at `onmouseenter` event that increases progress and clear it case progress get's to 100, when the hover ends (`onmouseleave`) clear the previous interval case it's still running and do the same the other way around:

```js
const bar = document.querySelector('.prg');
const hoverMe = document.querySelector('.hoverMe');
let intrval;
let prg = 0;
hoverMe.onmouseenter = (e) => {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
   prg++;
    bar.style.width = prg + '%';
    bar.innerText = prg + '%';
    if(prg >= 100) {
     clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 50);
}

hoverMe.onmouseleave = () => {
 clearInterval(interval);
 interval = setInterval(() => {
   prg--;
    bar.style.width = prg + '%';
    bar.innerText = prg + '%';
    if(prg <= 0) {
     clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 50);
}
```

```css
div {
    background: cyan;
}
.prg {
    height: 16px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverMe">
<div class="prg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to adapt this to node JS?